# Can a weght be applied to each element is a pattern matching algorithm?

Tags: regex, algorithm, needleman-wunsch

Is there a way to write an algorithm for the following example **without terrible runtime** ?

This algorithm should be able to match two strings however each value in the string has a weight. (0-1: 0 meaning non essential, 1 meaning essential) If the weight is not 1, then the chars do not have to match and therefore a mismatch can occur. This is easier to explain with an example.

Pattern:
`public static void main (String []args){`

Sample:
`public static void main (List<String> command_line_vals) {`

Weights:

- 1 for `public static void main (`
- 0.5 for `String []`
- 0.1 for `args`
- 1 for `) {`

The goal is to have these two match successfully. If the arguments are closer to the pattern, then it is scored higher. In this example it would mean that `String []vals` would rank higher than the above sample.

This is different from needleman-wunsch because if the char has a rank of !=1 then it should not match at all.

I would use `regex` however this would not allow me to rank the ones that do match. Would using regex first(wildcards for all non 1 valued chars), then needleman-wunsch on those that match work?

Suggestions and brain storming is welcome.

Thank you for your time.